# icon shows in html but cannot be located

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests
import json
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924013622003144"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 2)

x_path = '//div[@class="button-link react-xocs-icon-only-link button-link-primary button-link-icon-only xh-highlight"]'
icon = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, x_path)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", icon)
time.sleep(50)
```

[image]

The `email icon` as highlighted is shown in the html. But when I tried to click it, it raised the NoSuchElementException error. It menas the icon cannot be located. I feel very confused. Please provide any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Provided xpath doesn't match any element on this page.

Seemed like you're trying to get "Open author info" icon.

It's unique locator is CSS selector `.button-link-icon-only[data-xocs-content-type=author]`

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get(url)

icon = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.button-link-icon-only[data-xocs-content-type=author]')))
icon.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But the code doesn't work. I want click the email icon.

Answer (score 0):

The provided XPath appears to be nearly accurate. However, it seems there is a discrepancy in the specified tag name, which should be "button" rather than "div." The attribute value provided appears to be correct, but the inclusion of "xh-highlight" at the end is unnecessary.
You can provide the XPath like this:

```
//button[@class='button-link react-xocs-icon-only-link button-link-primary button-link-icon-only']
```

I modified the given code for this purpose

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924013622003144"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
x_path = "//button[@class='button-link react-xocs-icon-only-link button-link-primary button-link-icon-only']"
icon = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x_path)))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", icon)
time.sleep(5)
```

I have also provided an additional [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OchD0.png) from which the XPath was derived